# How to see spaces in GitKraken free version

Tags: git, github, gitkraken

I use GitKraken and and it is really cool tool!
Is it possible to see spaces in GitKraken?

For example, there are spaces, but GitKraken shows no spaces:

[image]

But another git visual tool shows spaces:

[image]

Is it possible to see spaces in free version of GitKraken?

Comment: My version of Git Kraken does show diffs for spaces. I don't think they'll go through the effort to modify a git diff (working around an already stable `git`)

Comment: @ClamentJohn is your GitKraken a free version? Does your GitKraken automatically set cursor to edited places when you edit file?

Comment: Oh, sorry. Mine is a student membership GitKraken.

Comment: I do not think any version of GK shows whitespace symbols.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using GitKraken version 4.0.5 (MacOS and Windows) and spaces are shown:

[image]

You have however a designated button for hiding spaces (on the top-right corner):

[image]

Which results (same source with spaces):

[image]

Maybe is it turned on on your client?

Comment: This shows the spaces as being highlighted, but I believe OP is looking for white space indicator glyphs. This is shown in his post by red middle aligned dots (and what I was looking for that brought me here). The benefit to the glyphs is being able to tell tabs vs spaces, how many spaces, and EOL characters.